# Propositional parameters

Tags: bash

below is an extract from a shell script i am tring to make, it is supposed to allow 
a user to supply files they want to view and the script prints the first lines of 
the each file and asks if they want to delete them.  i have marked where the errors are, i know i am using the $ improperly.

any help would be appreciated
thanks :)

```
count=1

while [ $# -ge $count ]

do
        head $"$count"//error here
    echo -e "Delete file $$count?? (y/n):"//error here

    read answer
    case $answer in
               Y|y)rm $"$count"//error here
                 echo -e "File $$count deleted\n" ;;//error here
               N|n)echo -e "File $$count NOT deleted\n" ;;//error here
               *)echo "Invalid Command";;
    esac            

    count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

Comment: The term is "positional" not "propositional".

Answer (score 2):

Using *positional* parameters in this case is silly, because you do not care about the position; only about its actual value. Use bash's `$@` array:

```
for file in "$@"; do
    head "$file";
    read -p "Delete file \"$file\"? (Y/N) " answer;
    case "$answer" in
        Y|y) rm -v "$file";;
        N|n) echo "File \"$file\" was not deleted.";;
        *) echo 'Invalid command';;
    esac;
done;
```

- Used "$@" instead of messing about with `$1` and `shift`.
- Quoted parameters when using them in commands.
- Specified a prompt for `read` instead of first `echo`ing it.

Comment: Sure there is, but it is silly. Change the first line to: `while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do` and add `file="$1"; shift;` between the first line and the one with `head`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
# loop till you have filenames
while [ $# -ge 1 ]
do
        # display the first 10 lines for 1st file.
        head $1

        echo -e "Delete file $1?? (y/n):"
        read answer

        case $answer in
        Y|y)rm $1
        echo -e "File $1 deleted\n" ;;

        N|n)echo -e "File $1 NOT deleted\n" ;;
        *)echo "Invalid Command";;

        esac            

        # shift the parameters.
        # you loose 1st argument, 2nd argument becomes 1st
        # $# is decremented.                                                                                                                                                                                   
        shift
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the user can supply multiple files to view, hence why I have a loop.  Thanks again for the reply though :)

Comment: @mrblippy: In this case user can supply any number of filenames on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be trying to do is called "indirection". You can use it to access the positional parameters, but using `shift` or using `for file` as in [janmoesen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511478/propositional-parameters/3511597#3511597) would be preferable.

Here's how indirection would work:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1
while (( count <= $# ))
do
    echo "${!count}"
    ((count++))
done
```

You would use `${!count}` in the places you have "$$count" in your script.

By the way, as you can see in my example, it's not necessary to use `expr` to increment your variable.